# How to create reusable AngularJs directives that copy existing directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am in the process of creating a few reusable directives for common controls in our application.

For example we have a snip-it of html for amount text boxes

```
<div class='amount'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='dollars'/>
</div>
```

From there I started to create my directive:

```
app.directive("amount", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<div class='amount'><input type='text'/></div>",
        replace: true
    }
});
```

Which renders the following `<html/>`

```
<div class="amount ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="dollars">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Now the `ng-model` is on the `<div/>` which is not what I want, so I need to create a scope and attach it to the `ngModel` and things are happy again.

```
app.directive("amount", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope:{
            ngModel: "="
        },
        template: "<div class='amount'><input type='text' ng-model='ngModel'/></div>",
        replace: true
    }
});
```

Everything works, but lets say I want to also add in a `ngChange` directive, does that mean I again need to alter my `scope` to include `ngChange: "="`?  Like so

```
app.directive("amount", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope:{
            ngModel: "=",
            ngChange : "="
        },
        template: "<div class='amount'><input type='text' ng-model='ngModel'/></div>",
        replace: true
    }
});
```

## The Question

Do I need to constantly modify the directives scope to include an infinite possible number of other directives I might require?  Or is there a way to copy the directives on the `<amount/>` element not to the `<div/>` but to the `<input/>`

E.g.

```
<amount my-awesome-directive="" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-model="dollarsAndCents" ng-click="aClick()" ng-show="shouldShow()"/>
```

Turns into

```
<div class="amount">
    <input my-awesome-directive="" type="text" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="aClick()" ng-show="shouldShow()" ng-model="dollarsAndCents"/>
</div>
```

Can something be done during the pre/post compile to copy them over or am I going about this all wrong?

## Update

I was able to get something working via simply looping over all attributes and using the `$compile()` service.  It does work, but is this correct?

```
app.directive("amount", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<div class='amount'><input type='text' /></div>",
        replace: true,
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {
            return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                var attributes = $(iElement).prop("attributes");
                var $input = $(iElement).find("input");
                $.each(attributes, function () { //loop over all attributes and copy them to the <input/>
                    if (this.name !== "class") {
                        $input.attr(this.name, this.value);
                    }
                });
                $compile($input)(scope);  //compile the input
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Given the following `<html/>` if you add any directive to the `<amount/>` it gets copied down to the `<input/>`

```
<div ng-app="app">
        <amount ng-model="dollars" ng-change="changed = 'I Changed!!!'" ng-click="clicked= 'I Clicked It!'" name="amount"></amount>
         <h1>{{dollars}}</h1>
         <h2>{{changed}}</h2>
         <h3>{{clicked}}</h3>
        <input type="button" value="Remove" ng-click="items.splice(items.indexOf(item), 1)"/>
        <hr/>
</div>
```

**[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/y3hUf/)**

Comment: This is an older post, but did you find an alternate way other than copying attributes and compiling?

Comment: A different approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42319665/913845

Answer (score -1):

Bind a controller and inject `$scope` for ease.

```
.controller('Amount', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myMoney = '2';
}])

.directive("amount", function(){
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    controller: 'Amount',
    template: "<div class='amount'><input type='text' ng-model='myMoney'/></div>",
    //Cleaner to include as URL if the partial is bigger.
    //templateUrl: '/views/amount.html',
    link: function(scope, controller) {}
});
```

Comment: Ok, how would this be handled if `ng-disabled` at one instance was `ctrl.isAmountDisabled()` and another instance `ng-disabled` happens to be `ctrl2.isSomeThingElseTrue()`  (templateurl is ideal but for question left it simple)

Comment: This also doesn't seem to solve the problem of having an arbitrary directive on `<amount super-cool=""/>` copy down to the `<input super-cool=""/>` (unless I am missing something)

Comment: @Mark Are you building your directives as modules that include their own controllers and injecting them into your app? Or are you building directives and using the app level controllers to control logic?

Comment: Ideally I would like the top parent controller of the directive to hold the business logic so the directive itself is dumb.   `<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"><amount ng-disabled="SomethignOnMyCtrl()"/></div>

Comment: @Mark You don't want your app level controller to control business logic of a reusable component. Ideally you want to be able to use this directive in "any" project. As soon as you add a dependency of an app level controller it's no longer modular. Your data, should get injected into the directive module as another module that is consumed by its own service and then passed into its own controller.

Comment: I want the directive, Reusable, any directive on `<amount/>` to be carried to the `<input/>`, and is dumb that it is does not contain any logic that is specific to a page/view/route/controller.