# Copy attributes from custom directive to input

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom driective which wraps input with div and adds a label.

```
<my-input label="My Label" name="myname" ng-model="mymodel" ng-pattern="/^[a-z]+$/">
```

I want to use optionally all of possible angular directives for input like ng-pattern, ng-minlength etc. Now it looks like this:

```
app.directive('myInput',[function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            name: '@',

            ngMinlength: '=',
            ngMaxlength: '=',
            ngPattern: '@',                
            label: '@'                
        },
        compile: function(element, attrs){

            if(!_.isUndefined(attrs['ngMinlength'])) {
                element.find('input').attr('ng-minlength', 'ngMinlength');
            }
            if(!_.isUndefined(attrs['ngMaxlength'])) {
                element.find('input').attr('ng-maxlength', 'ngMaxlength');
            }                
            if(!_.isUndefined(attrs['ngPattern'])) {
                element.find('input').attr('ng-pattern', attrs['ngPattern']);
            }               


        },
        template: '<div class="form-group">'
        + '<label>{{ label | translate }}</label>'
        + '<div>'
        + '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="{{ name }}" ng-model="ngModel">'           
        + '</div></div>'
    };
}]);
```

The problem is that I want use ng-pattern exactly the same as ng-pattern works in input, so I want to have possibility to use regexp in the ng-pattern and also scope variable with pattern (`$scope.mypattern = /^[a-z]+$/; ... ng-pattern="mypattern"`). How to manage this?

I want both working:

1.

```
<my-input label="My Label" name="myname" ng-model="mymodel" ng-pattern="/^[a-z]+$/">
```

2.

```
$scope.myPattern = /^[a-z]+$/
...
<my-input label="My Label" name="myname" ng-model="mymodel" ng-pattern="myPattern">
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I had to have two attributes `pattern` and `pattern-inline`. But still waiting for solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three answers for you.

1. In general, it is not recommended to support both a model property, and directly a String. This case is handled by a `=` declaration in your directive scope, and if you want to pass a String, you would use simple quotes. For instance ngBind works like this: `ng-bind="someModel"` or `ng-bind="'some string'"`
2. If you *really* want to, you can try to parse the expression. If it is parsable, it means it is a scope model. Otherwise, it is likely a string. See working example in the code snippet below:

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = "string from scope model";
})

.directive('turlututu', function($parse) {
 return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {},
   template: '<div class="tu">{{content}}</div>',
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
     try {
       scope.content = $parse(attrs.text)(scope.$parent);
     } catch(err) {
     } finally {
       if (!scope.content) {
         scope.content = attrs.text;
       }
     }
   }
 };
});
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; }

.tu { padding: 10px; margin: 10px; background: #f5f5f5; border-bottom: 2px solid #e5e5e5; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
  
  <turlututu text="hardcoded string"></turlututu>
  <turlututu text="model"></turlututu>
  
</div>
```

3. In the case of ngPattern, because curiosity in code will always help you, you can see in the source code of Angular that they test the attribute first character: if it is `/` it is considered a regexp, otherwise a scope model (see example below)

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = /[a-z]*/;
})

.directive('turlututu', function($parse) {
 return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {},
   template: '<div class="tu">{{content}}</div>',
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
     if (attrs.regexp.charAt(0) === '/') {
       scope.reg = new RegExp( attrs.regexp.substring(1, attrs.regexp.length-1) );
     } else {     
       scope.reg = new RegExp( $parse(attrs.regexp)(scope.$parent) );
     }
     
     scope.content = scope.reg.toString()
   }
 };
});
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; }

.tu { padding: 10px; margin: 10px; background: #f5f5f5; border-bottom: 2px solid #e5e5e5; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
  
  <turlututu regexp="/[0-9]*/"></turlututu>
  <turlututu regexp="model"></turlututu>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem - needed to treat my custom decorated input as if it was a regular input element. I also started with isolated scope but eventually decided it is not flexible enough. Having to add every attribute I might need gets old real quick.
So I came up with the below solution. Not sure if it is the correct/canonical Angular way, but works for me.

The idea is to build a "view model" object from directive's attributes and feed it to $interpolate. Any attributes not used in the view model are inserted into the actual < input /> element via the special **attributesToCopy** property of the view model. It does not create any new scopes, just puts it in the current scope.
This directive uses uses lodash kebabCase: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#kebabCase

If you don't want to include lodash you can use snake_case function from Angular itself, but it is not exposed via their API so you would need to copy-paste it somewhere in your code.

```
controlsModule.directive('myTextbox', ['$interpolate',function ($interpolate) {
    var tmpl =
    '<div class="form-group" title="{{hint}}"> \
                    <label class="{{labelClass}} control-label">{{label}}</label> \
                    <input type="{{type}}" class="form-control input-group-sm" {{attributesToCopy}} /> \
            </div>';

    var interpolate = $interpolate(tmpl);

    function buildModel(attrs) {

        if (!attrs.placeholder) attrs.placeholder = attrs.label;
        if (!attrs.labelClass) attrs.labelClass = "col-sm-3";
        if (!attrs.type) attrs.type = "text";

        return {
            label: attrs.label,
            labelClass: attrs.labelClass,
            type: attrs.type
        };
    }

    function template(tElement, tAttrs) {
        var model = buildModel(tAttrs);
        var atc = "";

        for (var attr in tAttrs) {
            if (!(attr.lastIndexOf('$', 0) === 0) && tAttrs.hasOwnProperty(attr) && !model[attr]) {
                    atc += ' ' + _.kebabCase(attr); //converts to snake_case , uses lodash/uderscore
                    if (tAttrs[attr] !== attr) {
                        atc += '="' + tAttrs[attr] + '" ';
                }
            }
        }

        model.attributesToCopy = atc;
        return interpolate(model);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: template
    };
}]);
```

Usage:

```
    <my-textbox type="number" ng-model="foo" ng-min="0" ng-max="5" required></my-textbox>
```