# Multiple Data Bindings in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, json, html, css

I am new to Angular and would like to know if something like this is possible:

I'm calling data to each story using JSON. Once the story is clicked I would like it to be sent to Javascript, then passed to a different HTML div, the player div.

Is there a way to do that? Or is that not possible with Angular?

For example:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller"storyCtrl">

 <div id="story-1" 
  class="play_button" 
  data-id="{id}" 
  data-title="{title}" 
  data-storyurl="{fullUrl}" 
  data-program="{program}" 
  data-programurl="{program.fullUrl}" 
  data-type="audio" 
  data-src="{soundcloudLink}" 
  data-item-type="story" 
  data-pub-date="{addedOn}" 
  data-excerpt="{excerpt}">
 </div>

 <div id="story-2" 
  class="play_button" 
  data-id="{id}" 
  data-title="{title}" 
  data-storyurl="{fullUrl}" 
  data-program="{program}" 
  data-programurl="{program.fullUrl}" 
  data-type="audio" 
  data-src="{soundcloudLink}" 
  data-item-type="story" 
  data-pub-date="{addedOn}" 
  data-excerpt="{excerpt}">
 </div>

<!--Here is where I would like the clicked data passed back to:-->

 <div id="player"> 
  <a href="{{story.Storyurl}}">{{story.Title}}</a>
  <a href="{{story.Programurl}}">{{story.Program}}</a>
 </div>

</body>
```

How would I go about creating the variables so that they display the data from the clicked story? Is it possible using Angular's two way binding? I would like them to display the data-information as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
 app.controller('storyCtrl', function($scope) {

  var story = [
     { 
         Id: 'data-id', 
         Title: 'data-title', 
         Storyurl:'data-storyurl', 
         Program: 'data-program',
         Programurl: 'data-programurl',
         Type: 'data-type',
         Src: 'data-src',
         Pubdate: 'data-pub-date',
         Excerpt: 'data-excerpt',
     },
  ];

  $scope.story = story; 

  });
```

Comment: You can create a callback and use `ng-click` to call it; This callback would be responsible for setting the `story` scope variable; I'm not sure I understand your question though, let me know if I misunderstood :)

Comment: Sure, my question is how can I get the data of whatever story div is clicked to pass through to the player div. 

Specifically, how can I create variables for all the data- elements of a clicked div that can be passed to a different div.

Comment: You can store them in a variable, instead of retrieving it directly from the $scope, them passing them through `ng-click`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy attributes from custom directive to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392559/copy-attributes-from-custom-directive-to-input)